# Emacs rinari-console in sandbox mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs, console, sandbox, rinari

Is there any way to to tell rinari-console to run in sandbox mode?
M-x rinari-console seems to be the only comand, and I don't know how to pass the ---sandbox flag to it. This should be simple, but my google-fu is completely failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Ruby developer, but [it looks like you can make Rinari prompt you for arguments with a prefix argument](https://github.com/eschulte/rinari/blob/be07b0f42aefa24c5d36c441d1f3f72e64fffaa4/rinari.el#L379): `C-u M-x rinari-console RET`.

Comment: Still getting used to Emacs source being great documentation. Perfect answer, thanks!